# Recomended API for developing PACS Server

Tags: c#, api, sdk, dicom

I'm newbie in DICOM and PACS server. In my company, I have to develop complete PACS server (including MWL, MPPS, DICOM viewer, etc). Now, I am currently research using Dvtk library on .Net C#.

My question: Is Dvtk suitable for developing complete PACS server? If not, then what API is suitable for this project?

Answer (score 2):

The [LEADTOOLS PACS Imaging SDK](https://www.leadtools.com/sdk/medical/pacs) can help you develop a complete, end-to-end solution, including DICOM viewer, 3D, MWL, MPPS, and much more.  Thousands of developers, like you, have used LEADTOOLS to successfully see their solution through to completion (including FDA approval).

You can download a free evaluation SDK from here: https://www.leadtools.com/downloads

The evaluation includes many applications with source code, so you will not have to start from scratch.  Also, LEADTOOLS technical support is free, starting with your evaluation.  We can help you get a proof of concept put together before making a purchasing decision.

Disclaimer: I am an employee of this product

Answer (score 1):

For C#/.net environment, I suggest using [fo-dicom](https://github.com/fo-dicom/fo-dicom), which is an open source library implemented in c#, with an exception of the image encoders (C++).

I have developed an entire radiology suite with it without issues, as it is an active project: C-Store, MWL, MPPS, etc.

You can incorporate it into your VS solution by using NuGet.